# C# - Redirect process output of game (UDK) server

Tags: c#, process, output, server

I am attempting to redirect the output of a game server process, but I'm not receiving most of the outputs.

[Here's a image of what such a server looks like.](https://udn.epicgames.com/Three/rsrc/Three/ReplicationPatternRepNotify/RepNotifyClientConsoleWindow.png)

Now, I am able to receive the yellow lines, but everything else just isn't showing up, neither in the console or at my end.

Any thoughts?

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = file;
p.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHandler);
p.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(ErrorHandler);

p.Start();
p.BeginOutputReadLine();
p.BeginErrorReadLine();

private void OutputHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
{
    ...
}

private void ErrorHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you also need to flush output buffer at the moment it outputs something. Without flushing, the output buffer could last until the external process is exited; this makes it impossible for the main application to capture the output "live"